# Python: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int' Is there any way i can fix this?

Tags: python, typeerror, python-turtle

I am making a ping pong game with python. When I run it and press w TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int' appears in the terminal. I am using vscode.
`

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Ping Pong By @TheMayoKing")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

#Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

#Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(+350, 0)

#Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape("square")
ball.color("white")
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)

#function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor
    y += 20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

#KeyboardBinding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, "w")

#MainGameLoop
while True:
    wn.update()
```

`
Please help.

I press w. It goes up, No. It doesn't move and this "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'" appears.

Comment: you are missing the braces after `paddle_a.ycor()` to assign the current y coordinate value to `y`

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the parentheses after the `y = paddle_a.ycor`. That returns the method, and not the int.

Use  `y = paddle_a.ycor()` and that should get you past that error.